# How to disable trimming of inputs in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've found some strange behavior: angular trims model values by default. And quick googling doesn't help me to solve this problem. I've found `ng-no-trim` directive proposals, `ng-trim` and so on. But nothing works.

I've provided a little snippet that represents this issue below.

```javascript
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.text='';

  $scope.$watch('text', function (newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  });
}
```

Also you could try this snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/ibosub/1/edit).

I've added a textarea that is in sync with model `text`. But it doesn't react for watching when add new trailing spaces or break the line to new one.

What could I do to turn off this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The directive in question is new in 1.1.1; you can see it working using [JS Bin snippet](http://jsbin.com/ibosub/11/edit).

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="text" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've included 1.1.1 version and now it works great.

Comment: No problem. Perhaps worth noting is that 1.1.2 is currently the latest unstable.

Comment: Could you tell me one more thing. I've added `ng-trim='false'` and when I type inside the textarea I need to duplicate it's content in some `div`, but replace '\n' with `br`. But my replacement doesn't work. BR is inserted only after I've typed one more char at new line. Any thoughts? Example: http://jsbin.com/ibosub/12/edit

Comment: @InviS `String.prototype.replace()` with a string parameter replaces only once. Use regexp for multiple replacements.

`$scope.clone = $scope.text.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');`

Answer (score 3):

Fallback for angular 1.0.x

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('ngTrim', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority: 300,
        link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs, ngModel) {
            if (iAttrs.ngTrim === 'false') {
                // Be careful here. We override any value comming from the previous
                // parsers to return the real value in iElem
                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function() {
                    return iElem.val();
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vXCnj/3/

Answer (score 3):

You can enable/disable trim option by using ng-trim=true/false.
Ref https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Comment: Good to know. Never heard of this directive before!

Comment: For me it was new too @MartynChamberlin