# length of whitespaces-only strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little angularjs app:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value"/>
    <span>{{value.length}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = '  ';
});
```

it can be seen under: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Er26f/1/)

At first, it displays a length of 2. When I remove one of the whitespaces in the input field, it displays a length of 0. I don't understand this behaviour. Is this a javascript or angularjs issue?

How can I get the length of an input including leading and trailing whitespaces?

Comment: Just to note, when you add whitespace it also displays 0.

Comment: Angular is likely [trimming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the string value before setting it back on the `$scope`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958418/how-to-disable-trimming-of-inputs-in-angularjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input values are automatically trimmed (whitespace removed from beginning and end). Set `ng-trim` to false to disable trimming.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-trim="false">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Er26f/2/)